# uploading files to Dropbox, bypassing authorization page?

Tags: dropbox

I have a form with some upload file fields, and I want to store the files in a Dropbox folder. However, the API always asks you to register before uploading files.

Does anyone knows how to do it without having to go through the authorization page ??

I would like to click upload, and directly upload the file to my repository.

Comment: Can you provide us with some of your code, i.e. what have you tried (even if what you have tried hits the auth. page)?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the Dropbox API with a single pre-defined account. The Dropbox API wasn't designed for this use case, but it is possible. We don't recommend it though, especially for client-side apps. If you wanted to do this, you should accept the file upload to your server first and then make the upload API call with your pre-defined access token on the server only.