# Can the app permission/verification be bypassed for Dropbox API?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I really hope this isn't a stupid question. I'm in the same boat this person is/was I believe: [uploading files to Dropbox, bypassing authorization page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412786/uploading-files-to-dropbox-bypassing-authorization-page)

However, I'll explain in more detail.

I've built a custom asp.net file upload control that supports server side storage and AWS S3, and I want to add Dropbox.

From the api documentation: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

It appears that I have to first generate a token, verify the app, and then call https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize along with the token.

The problem is I want end-users to be able to install the control, add their app/secret key to the control settings, and it's ready to go when the page loads.

So I'm not wanting to use the api for every John Doe to grant permission and upload files to and from their own dropbox.

Hope I'm making sense...  Here's some code:

```
        Dim appKey As String = "myappkey"
        Dim appSecret As String = "mysecretkey"
        Dim uri As Uri = New Uri("https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token")

        Dim oAuth As OAuthBase = New OAuthBase()
        Dim nonce As String = oAuth.GenerateNonce()
        Dim timeStamp As String = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp()
        Dim parameters As String = String.Empty
        Dim normalizedUrl As String = String.Empty
        Dim signature As String = oAuth.GenerateSignature(uri, appKey, appSecret, String.Empty, String.Empty, "GET", timeStamp, nonce, OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, _
                                                          normalizedUrl, parameters)

        signature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature)

        Dim requestUri As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(uri.ToString)
        With requestUri
            .AppendFormat("?oauth_consumer_key={0}&", appKey)
            .AppendFormat("oauth_nonce={0}&", nonce)
            .AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp={0}&", timeStamp)
            .AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method={0}&", "HMAC-SHA1")
            .AppendFormat("oauth_version={0}&", "1.0")
            .AppendFormat("oauth_signature={0}", signature)
        End With

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri(requestUri.ToString()))
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim queryString = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
        Dim parts = queryString.Split("&"c)
        Dim token = parts(1).Substring(parts(1).IndexOf("="c) + 1)
        Dim tokenSecret = parts(0).Substring(parts(0).IndexOf("="c) + 1)

        Dim queryString2 As String = String.Format("oauth_token={0}", token)

' the below code is what I want to bypass, as in verifying the app permissions by loading a Dropbox verification page.

Dim authorizeUrl As String = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?" + queryString2
```

Maybe I missed something elementary here, or possibly an online example.

So again, visitors to my website would be able to use this file uploader, like lets say they're uploading a profile picture for their profile page... It's my dropbox account for the website. Hope this makes sense.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So you're wanting users to authenticate against your DropBox account so they can upload their profile pictures to your account?

Comment: @TyCobb Correct. Just picture a social site, and instead of using the file system for file storage, I want to use Dropbox. (Ie: /Dropbox/Users/Uploads/Picture.jpg)

Comment: @user1447679, you said "Correct," but then the rest of what you said didn't seem to match. :-) Are you really saying every user who installs your control should be uploading files to *your* account? That doesn't seem like a good idea. If they're supposed to upload to *their* account, then they'll need to authorize the app. (Otherwise it won't have permissions to write to their Dropbox.)

Comment: @smarx No I apologize for the lack of clarity. I want other website developers to be able to install the uploader on their site. They put in their own app key/secret. They can use the uploader on their site however they want. "Dropbox" confuses the question itself. I used an example of a social site. When someone uploads a profile picture on Facebook it's stored on Facebook's servers. I'm wanting to use Dropbox as an option on this control, so the website owner/developer would setup their own Dropbox account.

Comment: In the same way someone could use Amazon S3 for file storage for their website, or Azure... I want to integrate Dropbox.

Comment: I guess I'm still not following which Dropbox account people will upload to. There's you (software author), developers who integrate on their website (developers), and end users who visit the websites (users). When a file gets uploaded to Dropbox, which of those accounts does it go into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the goal is to have each developer who deploys the code use their Dropbox account as the upload destination.

Each developer will need to auth with their account and put their access token in (code or config). See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/94/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account for a one-click way for devs to do that with their own app. But note that this is an odd use of Dropbox, in that Dropbox is usually meant for each end user to authorize with their own account and use their own Dropbox.

Comment: Oh... MY... Gosh. Googling and Googling and looking at examples, and I scanned right over this! Thank you Smarx.

Comment: Funny, I also just stumbled upon your repo OAuth2 - the hard way. Thought I'd throw out another thank you :)